# Keep navbar inside container while scrolling down

Tags: html, css

Using bootstrap 4, I have a fixed navbar inside a container. At the top, it takes the whole width of page but when I start scrolling, it goes inside the container.

How can I make it start or when I scroll to the way top, be inside the container?

This part I added navbar scroll so when I scroll, it changes color and changes background color to active part.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbarScroll">
<!-- nav section -->
<div id="navbarScroll">
  <nav class="navbar container fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a><!-- took off brand name on left; only toggler -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navi" aria-controls="navi" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navi">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      <ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<!-- about section -->
<div class="backgroundColor">
  <div class="anchor" id="about"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row one">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/lyoon/image/upload/c_scale,h_350,w_350/v1503457656/02_27_16_2_u3qrdf.jpg" class="img-fluid profpic" alt="caught a bass!">
      </div>
      <div class="description col-md-8">
        <p>Front-End Developer and UX/UI Designer, with experience in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Familiar with Bootstrap for CSS, jQuery for JavaScript and responsive web design.</p><hr>
        <p>Junior Web Developer who loves programming, music, and walks</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- portfolio section -->
    <div class="anchor" id="portfolio"></div>
    <div class="row two">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3 class="titleport">Portfolio</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="secondPara">To view demo, click image. To view code, click app title below image
          <br />
          All made with HTML, CSS, JavaScript
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row three">
      <div class="col-md-6 img-section1">
        <figure>
          <a href="https://lawrenceyoon.github.io/Score_Keeper/">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/lyoon/image/upload/c_scale,h_400,w_500/v1509214906/Screen_Shot_2017-10-28_at_11.21.21_AM_w2ieuq.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Score Keeper Game">
          </a>
          <figcaption><a href="https://github.com/lawrenceyoon/Score_Keeper">Score Keeper</a></figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 img-section2">
        <figure>
          <a href="https://lawrenceyoon.github.io/Color_Game/">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/lyoon/image/upload/c_scale,h_400,w_500/v1509390097/Screen_Shot_2017-10-30_at_12.01.08_PM_fnjwbi.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Color Game">
          </a>
          <figcaption><a href="https://github.com/lawrenceyoon/Color_Game">Color Game</a></figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 img-section3">
        <figure>
          <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/lyoon/image/upload/c_scale,h_400,w_500/v1503458438/01_19_16_2_y3l4th.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="3rd beach pic">
          <figcaption>Replace pic later3</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 img-section4">
        <figure>
          <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/lyoon/image/upload/c_scale,h_400,w_500/v1503458438/01_19_16_2_y3l4th.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="4th beach pic">
          <figcaption>Replace pic later4</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- contact section -->
    <div class="anchor" id="contact"></div>
    <div class="row four">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3 class="titlecontact">Contact</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="contactme">Please send me an email if you want to contact me!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- end of container -->
</div><!-- end backgroundColor -->
```

Here is the CSS section.

```
/* all */
body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Slabo', serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.container {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.backgroundColor {
  background-color: rgb(163, 167, 168);
}

.anchor {
  position: relative;
  top: -46px; /* this was added for navbar room after clicking on nav links */
}

/* navbar section */
.navbar {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav 
.nav-link.active, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-
light .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link {
background-color: rgb(163, 167, 168);
  color: white;
}

/* about section */
.one {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  margin-top: 46px; /* added here or navbar will be over profile 
picture MUST MATCH .ANCHOR */
}

.profpic {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin: 30px auto 0px auto;
}

.description {
  margin: 30px auto;
}

/* portfolio section */
.two {
  text-align: center;
}

.titleport {
  padding: 30px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

p.secondPara {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.three {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.img-section1, .img-section2, .img-section3, .img-section4 {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  border-radius: 5%;
}

figure {
  margin: 0px;
}

figcaption {
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

/* contact section */
.titlecontact {
  padding: 30px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}

.contactme {
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0px;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

a:hover {
  color: rgb(1, 193, 213);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.iconContainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

a.icons {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Change margin-top to padding-top.

**Explanation**:

Padding is the space between the content and the border. Margin is the space outside the border. Margin was pushing the entire div down which causes the body background color to show, which happens to be white. So it's sort of an optical illusion.

You could also change the body background to match the grey background color.

```
.one {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    padding-top: 46px; /* added here or navbar will be over profile 
    picture MUST MATCH .ANCHOR */
}
```

Comment: Oh that was an easy fix... 0.0 Thanks so much! Do you know why it has to be padding-top, not margin-top?

Comment: Padding is the space between the content and the border. Margin is the space outside the border.

Margin was pushing the entire `div` down which causes the body background color to show, which happens to be white. So it's sort of an optical illusion.
You could also change the `body background` to match the grey background color.